# Cannot create new data in database using ViewModel shows "Server Error in '/' Application. Value cannot be null. Parameter name: entity"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to create new data in database. I'm using ViewBag to load dropdown list. When I use model, i can create new data in the database. But when i use ViewModel, It shows above Exception.

Controller:-

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    private qsoft_dbfirstEntities db = new qsoft_dbfirstEntities();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Department_Id = new SelectList(db.departments, "id", "department_name");
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id,employee_name,department_id")]EmployeeViewModel employee)
    {
        db.employees.Add(employee.Employee);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Employee");
    }
}
```

Comment: why you are using employee.Employee in the add ? do we have an employee property within EmployeeViewModel ? Also check in the Employee view model if the data is getting bind properly

Comment: Yes. `public class EmployeeViewModel
    {
        public employee Employee { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: so is the Employee property in the Employee view model binding properly with all values send from view ?

Comment: Yes. Thats right